# JSON Response printing issue for Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, parsing, printing

I am hitting an API to get ID based on parameters passed from database, script below shows only the API part. I am passing 2 columns. If both the columns have data in the database, then it hits API-1. If only 2nd column has a data then it hits API-2 via API-1. The problem is in printing the response, because both the API have different structure.

Pretty Structure of API-1:

`"body": {
    "type1": {
            "id": id_data,
            "col1": "col1_data",
            "col2": "col2_data"}
            }`

Pretty Structure of API-2:

`"body": {
    "id": id_data,
    "col2": "col2_data"
            }`

Python Code:
`print (resp['body']['type1']['id'], resp['body']['type1']['col1'], resp['body']['type1']['col2'])`

As you can see structure is different and 'print' works if both the parameters are sent but it fails when only 2nd column is sent as parameter.

Comment: Did you try `dict.get()` and check if keys are present? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Create a printer that handles both cases graciously:

```
id_data = "whatever"
data1 = {"body": { "type1": { "id": id_data, "col1": "col1_data", "col2": "col2_data"} }}
data2 = { "body": { "id": id_data, "col2": "col2_data"}}

def printit(d):
    # try to acces d["body"]["type1"] - fallback to d["body"] - store it
    myd = d["body"].get("type1",d["body"])
    did = myd.get("id")      # get id
    col1 = myd.get("col1")   # mabye get col1
    col2 = myd.get("col2")   # get col2

    # print what is surely there, check for those that might miss
    print(did)
    if col1: 
        print(col1)
    print(col2 + "\n") 


printit(data1)
printit(data2)
```

Output:

```
# data1
whatever
col1_data
col2_data

# data2
whatever
col2_data
```